# List of commands with Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

**Hi guys,**

I have three commands for copy/paste the folder with a similar path. I using this code:

```
        from subprocess import Popen, PIPE        


        cmd_list = [
            'cp -r /opt/some_folder_1/ /home/user_name/',
            'cp -r /var/some_folder_2/ /home/user_name/',
            'cp -r /etc/some_folder_3/ /home/user_name/',
        ]
            copy_paste = Popen(
            cmd_list,
            shell = True,
            stdin = PIPE,
            stdout = PIPE,
            stderr = PIPE

        )

            stdout, stderr = make_copy.communicate()
```

But for the copy/paste three folders, I should three times run code.
Could you help me with these guys?

**Thank you!**

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want to do? There is no need of running three times the code for copying three files, since you do that in a single Popen by passing cmd_list to it.

Comment: @Nastor  "a single Popen by passing cmd_list to it" is already exactly what he's doing.

Comment: Hi, @Nastor!

I would like to try using the subprocess in my code, and I'm wondering if it is possible to use subprocesses via the command list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
import subprocess       


cmd_list = [
    ['cp', '-r', '/opt/some_folder_1/', '/home/user_name/'],
    ['cp', '-r', '/var/some_folder_2/', '/home/user_name/'],
    ['cp', '-r', '/etc/some_folder_3/', '/home/user_name/'],
]
for cmd in cmd_list:
    res = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
    # stdout and stderr are available at res.stdout and res.stderr
    # An error is raised for non-zero return codes
```

When passing a list into `Popen` or any of the other subprocess functions, you're not able to pass multiple commands in the `cmd_list`. It is expected that the first item in the list is the command you are running, and everything else are parameters for that one command. This restriction helps keep your code safer, especially when using user supplied input.

Another options is you can join everything together into a single command with a double ampersand. When doing so if one command fails the remaining commands won't run.

```
copy_paste = Popen(
    ' && '.join(cmd_list),
    shell = True,
    stdin = PIPE,
    stdout = PIPE,
    stderr = PIPE

)
```